# C++ Heap exception upon deleting an Array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, exception, heap-memory

I have this code:

```
class Vards 
{
    public:
    char vards[31];
    //some functions here//
};

Vards *Arr;
Arr = new Vards[word_count];//dynamically allocates 

//do some stuff

delete[] Arr;
```

And everything seems to be fine, but upon the last line VS gives me an exception and breaks to some strange places like:

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData
        )
{
        if (!pUserData)
            return FALSE;

        if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
            return FALSE;

        return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
}
```

And then to

```
void __cdecl _free_base (void * pBlock)
{

        int retval = 0;


        if (pBlock == NULL)
            return;

        RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Free_hook, (pBlock, 0));

        retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
        if (retval == 0)
        {
            errno = _get_errno_from_oserr(GetLastError());
        }
}
```

Is this supposed to be normal? My CodeBlocks can't even run the program (although it compiles it) so I am wonder if there is something I am doing wrong.
I can't google anything that would relate to this. Are there some kind of limitations with object arrays, or am I doing something wrong?

[EDIT] Based on Matts and barak manos advice, I thoroughly checked entire code and found that indeed I was acessing the array with a too large index in one specific place.
Could please one of you post your comment as an answer so I can mark this answered?

Bonus question: If I did some damage to heap before deleting a)Why didn't it find it immediately? b)How does it find it upon deletion?

Comment: You probably have heap corruption elsewhere in the code (e.g. overrunning a buffer that was dynamically allocated).

Comment: Could it be that it only finds that the heap is corrupted on this line? I am going through the code line by line, and only on delete it throws the exception.

Comment: In your "do some stuff", check the following: 1. You are not attempting to access `Arr` with an index larger than `word_count-1`. 2. You are not attempting to access `vards` with an index larger than 30 (including mem-copy operations, and `str` operations when none of the 31 characters in `vards` is equal to 0).

Comment: Could you provide a small complete (compiling) example which reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, you probably are corrupting the heap somewhere. (Someone who commented this should make it an answer so they can take the credit.)

About your bonus questions:
When you write to an element of an array (for speed) there is no checking whether the index in within bounds in C and C++. (Of course, you will get a segmentation error is you try to write to memory that doesn't belong to you.)

Before and after the memory you get from new[], several specially formatted bytes are allocated for bookkeeping. When you use delete[], the validity of those bytes will be checked to detect a corrupt heap. If I'm not mistaken, if and how this works depends on your platform and compiler.